# Laravel 5.1 index.php throwing reflection error and could not locate the controller

Tags: redirect, routes, laravel-5.1

I am trying to setup my laravel 5.1 project in one of our testing server (LAMP - debian linux, apache 2.4). Copied the entire laravel project from dev machine to testing machine. Did the necessary configuration. We have created a custom controller named loginController. When i try to reach out http://192.168.0.1/index.php i am getting the below error.

My controller looks like -

```
namespace App\myfolder\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
    protected $username = 'username';

    public function __construct()
    {
        require app_path() . '/common/constants.php';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('myfolder/themes/' . SELECT_THEME . '/login');
    }
}
```

Please someone help.

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 741:
Class \App\myfolder\controllers\loginController does not exist

in Container.php line 741
at ReflectionClass->__construct('\App\locumnet\controllers\loginController') in Container.php line 741
at Container->build('\App\locumnet\controllers\loginController', array()) in Container.php line 631
at Container->make('\App\locumnet\controllers\loginController', array()) in Application.php line 674
at Application->make('\App\locumnet\controllers\loginController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 85
at ControllerDispatcher->makeController('\App\locumnet\controllers\loginController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 57
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), '\App\locumnet\controllers\loginController', 'index') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 708
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 710
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: `Class \App\myfolder\controllers\loginController does not exist` this is the part you should be concerned with. I assume your route is looking for a controller that either doesn't exist or is in the wrong directory or isn't properly namespaced. Perhaps check out those things and see if it solves the issue for you. Also with Laravel projects, controllers usually reside in the `app/http/controllers` folder

Comment: give me more infortion.add  loginController  code to your question

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Reason was that my controller name was LoginController.php but routes.php was searching for loginController.php. After changing the first letter to small case it started working.